# Spread out letters to fit the box (Gimp, Affinity Publisher)

Tags: character, bounding-box

I would like to produce a logo similar to this one:

[image]

The characters in different lines are different sizes, but the width of the bounding box in every line is exactly the same. How to achieve such effect either in Gimp (ideally) or in Affinity Publisher (these are the two tools I have). Other open source tools are also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use raster software to make logos. Better to use a vector image editor.

This is an example in made in Inkscape which is free and Open Source. Drop some guides to help you position the text, set the text alignment to centre, vertically centre the text using the Align and Distribute panel, select the text and adjust the kerning (letter spacing) until the letters touch the guides.

[image]

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need! Thank you, I will use Inkscape!